What is the difference of AssistantAgent, ConversableAgent and UserProxyAgent of autogen?
I use the multiple agents from autogen  https://microsoft.github.io/autogen/ .
There are at least three agents: AssistantAgent, ConversableAgent and UserProxyAgent.
What is the difference of AssistantAgent, ConversableAgent and UserProxyAgent of autogen?

ConversableAgent:

Primary Purpose: Base class for building customizable agents that can
talk and interact with other agents, people, and tools to solve
tasks.
Customizable: Highly customizable, allowing for the
integration of LL.M.s, people and tools.

AssistantAgent:

Primary Purpose: Act as an AI assistant to generate responses using LLM, such as writing Python code.
Human Input: Do not request human input (human_input_mode = "NEVER").
Code Execution: Do not execute code (code_execution_config = False).

UserProxyAgent:

Primary Purpose: Act as a human agent, soliciting human input at
every interaction and executing code when needed.
Human Input: Always
request human input (human_input_mode="ALWAYS").
LLM Usage: LLM-based
responses are disabled by default, but can be enabled.

References:

https://microsoft.github.io/autogen/docs/tutorial/human-in-the-loop
https://microsoft.github.io/autogen/docs/Use-Cases/agent_chat

